# How can I display dynamic state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I create a `state` dynamically, but I need use this `state` in my render.

See my issue:

```
handleChange = (name, checked) => {
  this.setState({
    [name]: checked,
  })
}
```

So, in my `render` how can I display my `[name]` state? (I don't know his name, since it's dynamic)

```
render(){

  console.log(this.state....?)

  return(
    <p>Hello</p>
  )
}
```

My function `handleChange` is called when I checked my checbkox. So, if I have 5, 10, 20 checkboxes how can I display my `[name]` state?

**----> UPDATE - FULL CODE <----**
I'm using a hover propriety to display my checkbox:

CSS using material ui:

```
  hideCheckbox: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  showCheckbox: {
    display: 'initial',
  },
```

My main class:

```
export class Item extends Component {

state = { 
  isHovering: true,
  checkboxChecked: false,
}

handleGetCardSelected = (id, checked) => { 
 //Here I set isHovering to display my checkbox
 //checkboxChecked is a control variable to always display the checkbox if it's checked

  if(checked){
    this.setState({
      isHovering: !this.state.isHovering,
      checkboxChecked: true,
    })

  } else {
    this.setState({
      checkboxChecked: false,
    })
  }
}

handleMouseHover = () => {
  if(!this.state.checkboxChecked){
    this.setState(this.toggleHoverState);
  }
}

toggleHoverState = (state) => {
  return {
    isHovering: !state.isHovering,
  };
}
return(
 <div 
   onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover} 
   onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
  >
   <div className={`
     ${this.state.isHovering && classes.hideCheckbox }
     ${this.state.checkboxChecked && classes.showCheckbox}
    `}>
      <CheckBoxCard handleGetCardSelected={this.handleGetCardSelected}/>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div 
   onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover} 
   onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
  >
   <div className={`
     ${this.state.isHovering && classes.hideCheckbox }
     ${this.state.checkboxChecked && classes.showCheckbox}
    `}>
      <CheckBoxCard handleGetCardSelected={this.handleGetCardSelected}/>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div 
   onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover} 
   onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
  >
   <div className={`
     ${this.state.isHovering && classes.hideCheckbox }
     ${this.state.checkboxChecked && classes.showCheckbox}
    `}>
      <CheckBoxCard handleGetCardSelected={this.handleGetCardSelected}/>
    </div>
  </div>
 )
 }
```

My CheckboxCard:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Checkbox } from '@material-ui/core';
const GreenCheckbox = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: '#43a04754',
    '&$checked': {
      color: '#43a047',
    },
    '&:hover': {
      color: '#43a047',
      backgroundColor: 'initial',
    },
  },
  checked: {},
})(props => <Checkbox color="default" {...props} />);

export default function CheckBoxCard(props){
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    idItem: false,
  });

  const handleCheckbox = name => event => {
    setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });

    let id = name
    let checked = event.target.checked
    props.handleGetCardSelected(id, checked)
  };

  return(
    <GreenCheckbox
      checked={state.idItem}
      onChange={handleCheckbox('idItem')}
      value="idItem"
      inputProps={{
        'aria-label': 'primary checkbox',
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

By default, my checkbox is hidden because my `state` `isHovering` is true, so the css variable hideCheckbox ('display: none') is set.

If I hover the element, is called `handleMouseHover` and the checkbox is displayed!

If I checked my checkbox, is set `checkboxChecked` for `true` and now I'm always displaying my checkbox! But, if I've two or more elements, all checkbox is displayed, because `checkboxChecked` is an unique element!

So, my `checkboxChecked` must be dynamic and per item! In this way, if is `checked`, only this checkbox will be displayed. The others no!

For first element: 
`${this.state.checkboxCheckedITEM1 && classes.showCheckbox}`

For second element: 
`${this.state.checkboxCheckedITEM2 && classes.showCheckbox}`

For second element: 
`${this.state.checkboxCheckedITEM3 && classes.showCheckbox}`

I update my code in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-16t91?fontsize=14

How can I do that?

Comment: You only want to `console.log` ?

Comment: it gets invoked by checkbox onchange event.

Comment: @Vencovsky No. I want check if my state is true or false and show especific css class using ternary

Comment: Please, if you have checkboxes show how you display the checkboxes, not only `<p>Hello</p>`. Add the full code.

Comment: Take a look at [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). You could pass your state into that to get the key value pairs you need to display

Comment: But if one of all the checkbox is true ? What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Guys, I inserted the full code explain my issue. I would be very gratefull if someone can help me o/

Comment: I uploaded my code at sandbox, you can access here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-16t91?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1):

> So, if I have 5, 10, 20 checkboxes how can I display my [name] state?

I think the smart way to do this is to nest components. Have an abstract parent component, that only renders the child component once the name is available. By using this pattern your problem can be solved.

[Check out this helpful article](https://medium.com/galvanize/six-common-patterns-in-react-js-part-1-of-3-d18457a71ef5)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your object to get only checked names.

```
Object.keys(this.state).filter(name => this.state[name]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a finite list of `checkbox` component

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        handleChange={() => this.handleChange('abc', !this.state[abc])}
        className={this.state['abc'] ? 'checked-class' : '' }
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In another situation whereby you render a list of dynamic checkbox.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  //Calling API to return dynamic list of checkboxes, and dump them into a state
  this.setState({ listOfCheckboxes });
}
```

Then in your `render` method, you will be using `.map` function

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
    {
      this.state.listOfCheckboxes.map(x => (
        <Checkbox
          handleChange={() => this.handleChange(x.name, !this.state[x.name]) }
          className={this.state[x.name] ? 'checked-class' : '' }
        />))
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By doing so :

`this.state[name]`

Answer (score 1):

You can look at `Object.keys()`, but if in future you would need to handle more than one state, iteration does not seem to solve the problem.

You could also give it a prefix `[name_${name}]: checked`, but would not recommend that at all.

If it is not a problem, use an object and you will have full controll over it.

```
this.setState({
  something: {
    name,
    checked  
  },
})
```